# Coupling windows in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, libreoffice

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and now I can't couple windows of LibreOffice automatically by dragging them to the edges. I tried with Ubuntu tweak tools and with unity tweak tools, but it neither works with LibreOffice nor with PDF viewer (these two are the ones I use normally). However, it works for Firefox and for the terminal.

I am currently using ubuntu:GNOME session.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is important to state what desktop environment you use, because the functionality depends on that.

Comment: $ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/ 
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 323 may  2 09:40 ubuntu-communitheme-snap.desktop 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 247 may  2 09:40 ubuntu.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 243 may  2 09:40 unity.desktop

Comment: OK, this learns us what different sessions you have, but not what session you are actually using. You can learn that with the following terminal command: echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP (or on the log in screen, click the cog icon to see what session currently is selected). I guess you might be using Unity, but that is only a guess.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my ignorance. I run your command and I am actually using ubuntu: GNOME

Comment: Please add this to your actual question by editing it. This is essential information to be able to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the answer to my question. However, it worked for what I wanted to do:
Using GENOME desktop environment I could not couple some windows and obviously, Unity Tweak Tools did not worked. So, I changed desktop environment from GENOME to Unity by following this tutorial: https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/

Hope this helps other people like me.